# Viewing output redirection file while program is writing to it

Tags: linux, io, output

I have a massive job running at the moment, and have it so that the output redirects to a file with the ">" operator. This program will end up running for many hours, but I'm nervous and want to check up on progress from time to time. To put my mind at ease in case this file stays blank until the program is completed: am I able to view this file and see the standard output being generated, or do I need to wait until the program ends to see these changes?

Comment: `$ tail -f /path/to/file` or `$ less /path/to/file` then SHIFT+F

Comment: thanks! that seems promising. @marekful